# Usage of Command Override in Azure Container Instances within Azure Portal

Tags: azure, docker, docker-for-windows, azureportal, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to deploy a Windows-based Container from a private repository within an Azure Container Instance using the Azure Portal and I'm not sure whether I use the "*Command override*" at the "Advanced" section properly (probably I do not). The thing is I've to pass an argument during runtime, which sets the value of a License Server, so that a specific application, which needs to establish a connection to the License Server, can start up.
In general, the run command for the container would look like:

```
docker run IMAGE:TAG -LicenseServer Port@Host
```

My entrypoint within the Dockerfile is a Powershell Script "Start.ps1", which requests the corresponding value of the mentioned License Server.

I've read the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-start-command) and therefore I've inserted following string to override and to pass the argument:

```
[ "cmd", "Start.ps1", "-LicenseServer", "<Port>@<Hostname>"]
```

After deploying the ACI, the Container gets the state "running" for a few seconds, after that, it's terminated again. According to logs, it didn't work anyway.

So I wonder, what would be the proper way to deploy the container to get it running?

Thank you a lot in advance!

In addition to my question, to get more context:
ACI was created within Azure Portal:

[image]

I've used following settings see JSON view:

```
{
"properties": {
    "sku": "Standard",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "containers": [
        {
            "name": "<name>",
            "properties": {
                "image": "<image name>",
                "command": [
                    "powershell",
                    "Start.ps1",
                    "-LicenseServer",
                    "<port>@<host>"
                ],
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "port": 80
                    }
                ],
                "environmentVariables": [],
                "instanceView": {
                    "restartCount": 1,
                    "currentState": {
                        "state": "Terminated",
                        "finishTime": "2021-04-28T06:06:22.2263538Z",
                        "detailStatus": "Container stopped per client request"
                    },
                    "previousState": {
                        "state": "Waiting",
                        "detailStatus": "CrashLoopBackOff: Back-off restarting failed"
                    }
                },
                "resources": {
                    "requests": {
                        "memoryInGB": 8,
                        "cpu": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "initContainers": [],
    "imageRegistryCredentials": [
        {
            "server": "<login server>",
            "username": "<user>"
        }
    ],
    "restartPolicy": "OnFailure",
    "ipAddress": {
        "ports": [
            {
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "port": 80
            }
        ],
        "type": "Public",
        "dnsNameLabel": "mycontainerdns",
        "fqdn": "mycontainerdns.westeurope.azurecontainer.io"
    },
    "osType": "Windows",
    "instanceView": {
        "events": [],
        "state": "Stopped"
    }
},
"id": "/subscriptions/<subscription id>",
"name": "<aci name>",
"type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
"location": "westeurope",
"tags": {}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. The command string, provided within "Command override" was wrong.
I've tried several versions, but it now worked with following:

```
[ "powershell", "C:/Windows/Scripts/Start.ps1", "-LicenseServer", "<port>@<host>" ]
```

Now I get logs and the running state of the container within the ACI deployment.

Before, I've tried as suggested in the first answer: (among others)

```
["powershell", "Start.ps1", "-LicenseServer", "<Port>@<Hostname>"]
```

But that seems not to work within ACI, as "Start.ps1" script couldn't be found ALTHOUGH I've set the working directory within the Dockerfile and of course it works within my Rancher deployment (by just providing "-LicenseServer PortatHost").

So, as conclusion you've to provide the full path to your file when it serves as Entrypoint within the Container.

Thank you a lot anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `cmd` just tell you when you need to connect to the windows container instance, you need to use the command:

```
az container exec -g resource_group_name -n container_group_name --container-name container_name --exec-command "cmd"
```

But when you want to overwrite the CMD command, you need to pass the arguments like this:

```
["powershell", "Start.ps1", "-LicenseServer", "<Port>@<Hostname>"]
```

It means you need to execute the Powershell script in the cmd terminal.

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer, but unfortunately it also didn't work...
Below the snippet of the json view:
...
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "containertest",
                "properties": {
                    "image": "<image name>:<some tag>",
                    "command": [
                        "powershell",
                        "Start.ps1",
                        "-LicenseServer",
                        "<port>@<host>"
                    ],
...

Comment: @bianconero Well, can you try the command `-LicenseServer Port@Host`. Remember, add the command when you create the ACI with the parameter `--command-line`.

Comment: unfortunately, none of the mentioned approaches worked related to the settings withn the Azure Portal worked. Even didn't get any logs. According to the Azure CLI approach: I don't have experience with that so far.

Comment: @bianconero Do you mean you work in the Azure portal? Can you share the method you use to create the ACI with your image?

Comment: @bianconero Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, I've added some more context by editing my origin post, maybe it help. In general it still doesn't work

Comment: @bianconero If you run the image well with the command `docker run IMAGE:TAG -LicenseServer Port@Host` locally, then it should work if set the command as `["-LicenseServer", "<port>@<host>"]`.

Comment: " If you run the image well with the command docker run IMAGE:TAG -LicenseServer Port@Host locally" --> yes, that works local at my host
but, if I set it in that way at "Commad Override" I get as a result a failed deployment of the whole ACI:

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"message":"Subscription deployment didn't reach a successful provisioning state after '00:30:00'."}]}

Comment: So, the Deployment works with ["powershell", "Start.ps1", "-LicenseServer", "port@host" ], but the containing Container doesn't get in a running state and in additon I can't see any logs

Comment: @bianconero When you run it locally, does it work fine?